# File could not be found - Extension Installer OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

When I'm trying to upload with Extension Installer a new theme to OpenCart 2.3.0.2 I'm getting a message:

> File could not be found!

I've enabled FTP and even when Im trying to upload QuickFix I'm getting a same error. Someone could help?

Comment: Do you have read permissions on that uploaded files?

Comment: Yeah, I have it

Answer (score 0):

In that type of error you can do following steps..

1.Go to Quickfix->localcopy.ocmod.

2.First check the zip file name in ".ocmod"extension.

3.The all files in the "upload" Folder please check.

4.Go to Extension->Extension Installer.

5.This is file path  "zipfile.ocmod->upload-> files".
Try this Its resolved your error.

Comment: I've .ocmod and all files are in "upload" folder... Still same problem.

Comment: Update my anser check  1 step.

Comment: As I said earlier, I can't install quickfix, cause Im getting a same error.

Comment: you try to install localcopy.ocmod?

Comment: Don't know what are you talkin about

Comment: ok.Then add directly the admin.catalig,image,system to old theme folder.its work.